# How to get the right div with this JQueryUI droppable code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using JQueryUI and I have 2 divs both droppable and resizable. My actual problem is that my draggables are added in both divs when I drop them. The 2 divs are detected when I drop in the bottom one, but ... I just want this one to be detected

I've tried some things with the CSS properties but I doesn't solved the problem.

I've made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Spydaxx/4ez2xtan/58/) so you can see the idea of my code.

These are my divs.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="divDrag" class="draggable">Drag Me !</div>
  <div id="div1" class="droppable resizable1"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="droppable resizable2"></div>
</div>
```

This is how I get the ID of the div where I drop.

```
  drop: function(event, ui){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  }
```

I want the alert to return "div2" when I drop something in the red div but it actually returns "div1" and then "div2"

Thanks for your help

Comment: One thing you can do is to set the red one to `min-height: 50px; bottom: 50px` but I don't know if that's a suitable solution.

Comment: Both divs have to stay at `bottom: 0` they are some kind of a "footer" in the project, this position can't change :/

Comment: Is it correct that the blue div is overlapping the red div? Because that is why you get both alerts, you simply drop it on both of them at the same time.

Comment: Yes. The red div is just in front of the blue one. Is there something I can do to get only the red div or I need to change the structure ?

Comment: You could try to put the second one inside the first one and then use this option: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the blue div is overlapping the red div, both of them receive your droppable.

Solution: Put the second droppable inside the first one an then use the `greedy` option to make sure only one droppable is receiving your draggable.

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy